# Get selected text from combobox in winium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, combobox

How can I get the selected option from a combo box using winium?

I used Select class from selenium. But it is throwing error like

> "org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: 'getElementTagName'
>   is not valid or implemented command".

I used the following code:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cmbLocation")));
String option = select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Comment: Check is your element is in iframe

Comment: I'm facing this problem while automating windows application. Not the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WebElement combo = winDriver.findElementById(autoID);
String option = combo.getAttribute("NameProperty");
```

The NameProperty changes with the value of selected option.